# How does one correctly use the df.duplicated() function with pd.read_excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm learning Python 3 and a small goal of mine has been to make a script that tells me if there are duplicates between 3 columns with 171 rows. I want it to catch "Apple" in any of the rows / columns if there are more than 1 basically. The data in the cells are strings, which I want to be put in a list.

The following code tells me Empty DataFrame and only returns my columns. I am able to see my rows when I use `df.head(x)` and I can see a Boolean return `False`  for all of the strings. I think it's trying to see if there are duplicates per row for the 3 columns but I need to work out iteration for returning any string in any column that is greater than 1.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Repo\Repo\My_Excel_File.xlsx")

dups=df[df.duplicated()]

print(dups)
```

If anyone would able to give me a hint towards the right direction to figuring this out, I don't necessary want an answer, it would be really appreciated.

I will return back with progress if interested.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In these duplicates, is the entire row exactly alike? Show what the duplicates are and take a look at what `df` has at those rows.